# Twitter Sign in using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, twitter, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I am trying to sign in to my web application (developed using Spring Boot) using social logins. The logins for Google & facebook are okay. But the for some reason there is a token issue in the twitter login. I have created the project in the twitter developer site obtained all the credentials. Please refer to my code below.

My Property file values are mentioned below.

twitter.client.client-id=XXXXXXX

twitter.client.client-secret=XXXXXXXX

twitter.client.access-token-uri=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

twitter.client.user-authorization-uri=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize

twitter.client.token-name=oauth_token

twitter.client.authentication-scheme=form

twitter.resource.user-info-uri=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json

The filter method

```
private Filter ssoTwitterFilter(String processingUrl, PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor) {
    OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter twitterFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            processingUrl);
    LOGGER.debug("processingUrl :{} ", processingUrl);

    twitterFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandlerAndRegistrationFilter());
    OAuth2RestTemplate twitterTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(twitter(), oauth2ClientContext);
    twitterFilter.setRestTemplate(twitterTemplate);
    UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(twitterResource().getUserInfoUri(),
            twitter().getClientId());
    tokenServices.setRestTemplate(twitterTemplate);
    tokenServices.setPrincipalExtractor(principalExtractor);
    return twitterFilter;
}
```

These are the bean configurations.

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("twitter.client")
public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails twitter() {
    return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("twitter.resource")
public ResourceServerProperties twitterResource() {
    return new ResourceServerProperties();
}
```

This is the error that I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvfWq.png)

Please can anyone shed some light on this. Because all the samples I found were related getting profile information from twitter where as i need a sample for sign in using spring Boot. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure Twitter login like this:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

@Autowired
private  UserAuthorizationService userAuthorizationService;
@Override
public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {

    cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("twitter.consumer-key"),
            env.getProperty("twitter.consumer-secret")
    ));



}

@Override
public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
    return new UserIdSource() {
        @Override
        public String getUserId() {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authentication == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
            }
            return authentication.getName();
        }
    };
}


@Override
public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
    InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository = new InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository(

            connectionFactoryLocator
    );
    return usersConnectionRepository;
}


@Autowired
private TwitterConnectionSignup twitterConnectionSignup;
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator;

@Autowired
private UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository;
@Bean
public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
    ((InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository) usersConnectionRepository)
            .setConnectionSignUp(twitterConnectionSignup);

    return new ProviderSignInController(
            connectionFactoryLocator,
            usersConnectionRepository,
            new TwitterSignInAdapter(userAuthorizationService));
}
```

}

Configure TwitterConnectionSignup:

```
@Service
public class TwitterConnectionSignup implements ConnectionSignUp {

@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@Override
public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {

   //add your logic to save user to your db
    return connection.getDisplayName();
}
```

}

Now configure TwitterSignInAdapter:

```
public class TwitterSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {
private UserAuthorizationService userAuthorizationService;

public TwitterSignInAdapter(UserAuthorizationService userAuthorizationService) {
    this.userAuthorizationService = userAuthorizationService;
}

@Override
public String signIn(String localUserId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest webRequest) {

    log.debug(" Email {}", localUserId);

    UserAuthDto userAuthDto = (UserAuthDto) userAuthorizationService.loadUserByUsername(localUserId);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken updatedAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userAuthDto, userAuthDto.getSocialId(),
            userAuthDto.getAuthorities());


    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(updatedAuth);
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = webRequest.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
    // add authentication to the session
    servletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(
            HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext());


    return "/";
}
```

}

Comment: Is this working with spring-security-oauth2? How would the HttpSecurity configuration look like for the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ?